# I'm testing FileSystemWatcher on a company network, can it cause a network violation when "watching"?

Tags: c#

I have access to multiple network drives at my company.
I'm running a test application that just monitors for created,updated,deleted and 
changed files/directories so my question is can the application "watching" the network
cause a network violation error i.e. spying ?

Thanks

Comment: are you saying "spying" is a type of "network violation error"?

Comment: Don't know. I'm just asking can using the FSWatcher throw violation errors of the type like when a user tries to log in with a wrong password x many times, those type of violation.

Comment: What the heck does "network violation" mean?  If you are trying to watch a directory that the user doesn't have access to then she'll get an "access violation".  You can't fix that, the system admin needs to take action.

Comment: @Hans, easy there, access violation is the proper term thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Don't see how this could be causing a network violotion errors?

(little side note, When using the systemfilewatcher over a network, its internalbuffer may not be greater than 64KB)

This can only happen when the network is also secured with extra security. Only way to find out is to try I guess..

Comment: BTW that internal buffer limit stuff is interesting, thanks for adding that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the network you are using is secured. Try it and find out.

On a network with no additional security monitoring a remote filesystem over a Windows Share via a FileSystemWatcher should not result in any problems.

Honestly, I can't think of any network security related issues I've ever had with a FileSystemWatcher.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely no, because they are usually not setup to inspect such specialized/proprietary network protocols, as the one which is used by .NET FileSystemWatcher to watch shared Windows drives.

Hope this helps.